# Flicker after finishing activity

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, flicker

I have an activity which uses the android theme `Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar.MinWidth`. This activity's only purpose is to display a notification. However, when I call `finish()` on this activity, if there is an activity/app open behind it, there will be a flicker. It seems like it's redrawing? Not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

After calling finish() in your activity, simply override the enter and exit animations of the activity by adding:

```
     overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```